# Unable to float right the google plusone button and get it to work

Tags: css, google-plus-one

I have a div that contains the Facebook Like button, Google plusone and an email button.  I've floated the div with float:right, however the Google plusone is no longer clickable.  The Facebook button is clickable across 2/3rds of the button.

When I remove the float:right from the class BookContain, it works ok (only its to the left).  I've tried removing float:right and replaced it with a relative positioning, but again Google plusone doesn't like it.

Here's an example... http://www.giftsthatthrill.com.au/gifts/skydiving-experiences/Coolum_Beach/AD9788

The CSS for the block is

```
.bookcontain {
margin-top:5px;
float:right;
}
.bookcontain ul {
text-align:left;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.bookcontain ul li{
text-align:left;
display:inline-block;
padding:0 2px 2px 0;
margin:0 0 0 5px;

}
 .bookcontain ul li.google {
vertical-align:top; 

}
```

I'm also finding that Firefox shows the Google plusone lower in the block ... this may be relevant to the issue above.

Any thoughts would be most appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons aren't clickable because they are hidden by the tabs div.

Here is a quick workaround...

Add this CSS to place the buttons above the tabs div:

```
#socialBookMarks{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

This will move the Google+ button up:

```
.google{
    position: relative;
    top: -13px;
}
```

I'll update soon with CSS to fix the positon of the buttons...

Comment: ah... that was very helpful.  The z-index does it.  Just checking the Google+ button placement as FF and IE are doing different things.

Comment: I can't get the google button to move up.

I tried:

    .google {
 top:-13px; 
 top:0px\9;
    }

with and without the hack.

Comment: Solution found by adding height:20px to containing div.  Many thanks for your help in getting the z-index out there... this had been an issue for a couple of weeks.... now solved.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes in your file.

Place `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` after `socialBookMarks` closing division.

Remove `vertical-align: top;` from CSS5.css line number 22

These changes will make your buttons stay at right side, clickable and aligned properly.

Comment: Many thanks Libin... the problem has manifested itself due to the z-index hiding the div.  Increasing the z-index brings the div to the front, so it becomes clickable.  The issue I now have is getting FF to show the GooglePlus in alignment.

Comment: Also noticed that there is a gap between your tabs and content. By removing `vertical-align: top;` from line 22 will fix it, but will messup the contents inside.

Comment: You're right.  Removing line 22 fixes it but its removal affects lots of pages including the content inside.  I'll keep searching for a way around it.

Comment: I've got a solution... added height:20px to the containing div.  Seems to work ok across IE, FF, Safari and Chrome.  Just want to thank you for your guidance.